# Question about a basic logic problem

Tags: logic

The following problem is presented in "How to prove it":

$\neg(P\land \neg S )$

Where P stands for "I will buy the pants" and S for, "I will buy the shirt".

Here is how I would tackle this:

I first look at the statement in parantheses, which just says P but (and) not S. Then the negation of this statement would be, not P but (and) S.

Where am I wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: $\neg(P\land \neg S )$ is $\neg P\lor S$

Comment: $\lnot (A \land B) \ne \lnot A \land \lnot B$.

Comment: Think this out: It is not true that I will by the pants but not the shirt.  So my buying the pants while not buying the shirt will not be true.  So maybe I won't buy the pants at all, or maybe I'll buy the shirt.  Of the four options I could buy neither, or a I could buy both, or I could buy just the shirt.  But in any event i'll either not buy the pants or I will buy the shir.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\lnot (A\land B) \ne \lnot A \land \lnot B$.

Instead $\lnot(A\land B) = \lnot A \lor \lnot B$.

So $\lnot (P\land \lnot Q) = \lnot P \lor Q$.

It is not the case that I will buy the pants but not the shirt.

So either I wont buy the pants *OR* I will buy the shirt.

Now it's possible that $\lnot P \land Q$.  It's possible that I *might* not but the pants but buy the shirt,  but I don't have to.  I could simple not buy the pants;  Then $\lnot (P\land \lnot Q)$, because $\lnot P$, whether  I buy the shirt or not.  Or I might simply buy the shirt; then $\lnot(P \land \lnot Q)$, because $Q$, whether I buy the pants or not.

Look at the truth tables.

$\begin{matrix} P & Q & \lnot (P\land \lnot Q) & \lnot P \lor Q& \lnot P\land Q\\T&T&\color{blue}{T}\text{(bcs $Q$ is not false)}&\color{blue}T\text{(bcs $Q$ is true)}& \color{red} F\text{(bcs $P$ is not false)}\\
T&F&F&F&F\\F&T&T&T&T\\F&F&\color{blue}{T}\text{(bcs $P$ is false)}&\color{blue}T\text{(bcs $P$ is not true)}& \color{red} F\text{(bcs $Q$ is false)}\\
\end{matrix}$

Comment: I get it with the truth tables. What threw me off was the definitive answer an online solution manual gave -"I will buy pants only when I buy the shirts.".
From: https://www.inchmeal.io/htpi/ch-1/sec-1.1.html

Comment: Yes: $\neg P\vee S$ says "either you do not buy pants, or you do buy shirts". Which means that *if* you buy pants, *then* you must have bought shirts ($P\to S$). So it says that "you *will* buy pants *only when* you buy shirts." (Note: that is just "only when", not "if and only when".)

Answer (score 3):

The negation outside the parentheses will change the **'and'** connective inside the parentheses to an **'or'** connective. Thus, the equivalent statement would be

> "I will not buy the pant **or** I will buy the shirt"

You can verify this by comparing the truth tables for $\lnot P\lor S$ and $\lnot (P\land \lnot S)$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the fast answer.

Answer (score 2):

(Posted after answer was accepted.)

Assuming that $P$ and $S$ are both true. Using a form of natural deduction, we have:

[image]